# Convert list of numpy arrays with different shapes into grayscale values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of images that are saved as numpy arrays.
I'm using the following code to change every image to be in grayscale :

```
def convert_to_grayscale(images:list):
  images_in_grayscale = []
  rgb_weights = [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]
  for image in images : 
    images_in_grayscale.append(np.dot(image,rgb_weights))

  return images_in_grayscale
```

I was wondering if there is a "pythonic" way to do it. Instead of iterating over the images, can I use np.dot with a matrix with different shapes ?

I tried using `np.dot(np.asarray(images),rgb_weights)` but I understand that all the vectors inside `numpy.array` must be in the same size. Is there any pythonic way to do it ?

Comment: Iteration on arrays of different size is very "pythonic".

Comment: A suggestion: Maybe add a filler value (`np.nan`) such that all your images are at the same size, according to the max size of each image dimension; Do the transformation with `np.dot(np.asarray(images_filled),rgb_weights)` as you suggested; Slice down each image according to the filled values (should be easy if the filler values are `np.nan`).

Comment: If your goal is a new list of image arrays (in the original shapes), the processing to/from a higher dimensional array may cancel any time savings from doing just one `dot`.